# can I use shadermaterial on particlesystem?

Tags: three.js, shader, fragment-shader, particle-system

what am trying to accomplish is to to put a different pixel data as the material of each particle, this is my train of thought:  set a canvas as texture of a PlaneGeometry, get pixel chunks of data from PlaneGeometry through fragment shader and put different chunks of that pixel data on any particle I want through the particlesystem's fragment shader, is this posible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use a custom `THREE.ShaderMaterial` with `THREE.ParticleSystem`s. Also worth noting is that if you simply want to use a canvas as a texture, you don't need to go through `PlaneGeometry`.

Comment: Thanks Tapio, the reason for going to PlaneGeometry is because, in order to get data directly from canvas I should use getImageDate() which is very slow, I intend to use fragmenshader of the Planegeometry to obtain this data instead

Comment: hey @Tapio can you check out this? thenks a lot http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697898/why-particle-system-with-shader-doesnt-work-three-js